# Fmt 0.9.0 broke my code, how can I make it compatible? Format.pp_set_formatter_stag_functions

Tags: ocaml

I have some code like:

```ml
(* Format.stag is an extensible variant type, we only want to handle Format.String_tag *)
exception UnhandledExtension of Format.stag

...

      let conditionally_raise e stack = match raise_errors with
        | true -> reset ppf; raise e
        | false -> Stack.clear stack
      in
      let color_tag_funs : Format.formatter_stag_functions =
        {
          mark_open_stag = (fun stag ->
              let _ = match stag with
                | Format.String_tag s -> begin
                    match Lexer.tag_to_code @@ String.lowercase_ascii s with
                    | Ok s -> Stack.push s stack
                    | Error e -> conditionally_raise e stack
                  end
                | other -> conditionally_raise (UnhandledExtension other) stack (* case not expected *)
              in
              collapse stack
            );
          mark_close_stag = (fun _ ->
              match Stack.is_empty stack with
              | true -> ""
              | false -> ignore @@ Stack.pop stack; collapse stack
            );
          print_open_stag = (fun _ -> ());
          print_close_stag = (fun _ -> ());
        }
      in
```

This was working perfectly when I ran it locally, until I rebuilt my switch today.

By perfectly, I mean that this line was never reached:

```ml
    stag -> conditionally_raise (UnhandledExtension stag) stack (* case not expected *)
```

When I pushed changes to github I found I was getting a test failure from my actions:

```
  [OK]          Fatal error: exception Spectrum.Printer.UnhandledExtension(_)
Raised at Spectrum__Printer.make_printer.M.prepare_ppf.conditionally_raise in file "lib/printer.ml", line 38, characters 18-25
Called from Fmt.store_op in file "src/fmt.ml" (inlined), line 626, characters 2-24
Called from Fmt.get in file "src/fmt.ml", line 628, characters 40-73
Called from Fmt.style_renderer in file "src/fmt.ml" (inlined), line 650, characters 25-52
Called from Fmt.styled in file "src/fmt.ml", line 745, characters 36-54
Called from Stdlib__format.output_acc in file "format.ml", line 1298, characters 32-48
Called from Stdlib__format.output_acc in file "format.ml", line 1298, characters 32-48
Called from Stdlib__format.kfprintf.(fun) in file "format.ml", line 1349, characters 16-34
Called from Stdlib__format.output_acc in file "format.ml", line 1298, characters 32-48
Called from Stdlib__format.kfprintf.(fun) in file "format.ml", line 1349, characters 16-34
Called from Alcotest_engine__Pp.Make.info in file "src/alcotest-engine/pp.ml", line 94, characters 8-41
Called from Alcotest_engine__Pp.Make.pp_result_full in file "src/alcotest-engine/pp.ml", line 136, characters 4-65
Called from Stdlib__format.output_acc in file "format.ml", line 1288, characters 4-20
Called from Stdlib__format.kfprintf.(fun) in file "format.ml", line 1349, characters 16-34
Called from Alcotest_engine__Core.Make.pp_event in file "src/alcotest-engine/core.ml", line 128, characters 6-168
Called from Alcotest_engine__Core.Make.perform_test in file "src/alcotest-engine/core.ml", line 237, characters 4-45
Called from Alcotest_engine__Monad.Extend.Syntax.(>|=).(fun) in file "src/alcotest-engine/monad.ml", line 32, characters 46-51
Called from Alcotest_engine__Monad.Extend.List.fold_map_s.inner in file "src/alcotest-engine/monad.ml", line 44, characters 26-34
Called from Alcotest_engine__Core.Make.perform_tests in file "src/alcotest-engine/core.ml", line 252, characters 6-276
Called from Alcotest_engine__Core.Make.result in file "src/alcotest-engine/core.ml", line 302, characters 19-44
Called from Alcotest_engine__Core.Make.run_tests in file "src/alcotest-engine/core.ml", line 356, characters 8-27
Called from Alcotest_engine__Core.Make.run_with_args' in file "src/alcotest-engine/core.ml", line 390, characters 6-304
Called from Cmdliner_term.app.(fun) in file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24
Called from Cmdliner.Term.run in file "cmdliner.ml", line 117, characters 32-39
Called from Cmdliner.Term.term_eval in file "cmdliner.ml", line 147, characters 18-36
Called from Cmdliner.Term.eval_choice in file "cmdliner.ml", line 265, characters 22-48
Called from Alcotest_engine__Cli.Make.run_with_args' in file "src/alcotest-engine/cli.ml", line 108, characters 6-164
Called from Junit_alcotest.run_and_report in file "alcotest/junit_alcotest.ml", line 65, characters 6-26
Called from Dune__exe__Printer in file "tests/printer.ml", line 111, characters 26-73
```

(not just a test failure, the test run itself crashes basically)

I rebuilt my local switch and the error reproduced locally too. I narrowed this down to a change in the `Fmt` library... rebuilding my switch had given me version `0.9.0` release a few weeks ago. (Downgrading to Fmt 0.8.10 makes it go away again).

I am pretty sure my code is breaking due to the change here https://github.com/dbuenzli/fmt/blob/master/src/fmt.ml#L608

So the Fmt lib now extends the `Format.stag` variant.

Unfortunately I don't understand what is going on, beyond I guess there are now two semantic tags formatters clashing with each other some how.

It only crashes in the tests, not when using my code in say utop.
Which makes sense, because in that case `Fmt` is not active (it comes in as a dependency of Alcotest).

I can recognise that `| other -> conditionally_raise (UnhandledExtension other) stack` is a bad idea, but if I replace it with `| _ -> ()` I get a different crash:

```
  [OK]          Fatal error: exception File "src/fmt.ml", line 647, characters 60-66: Assertion failed
Raised at Fmt.style_renderer_attr.dec in file "src/fmt.ml", line 647, characters 60-72
Called from Fmt.get in file "src/fmt.ml", line 629, characters 25-32
Called from Fmt.style_renderer in file "src/fmt.ml" (inlined), line 650, characters 25-52
Called from Fmt.styled in file "src/fmt.ml", line 745, characters 36-54
Called from Stdlib__format.output_acc in file "format.ml", line 1298, characters 32-48
...
```

So it's triggering the `assert false` case here: https://github.com/dbuenzli/fmt/blob/master/src/fmt.ml#L647

Comment: Here's a few options you could consider: 1) Ignore tags you aren't interested in instead of intentionally crashing. 2) Stay with fmt 0.8, unless there are reasons for needing to upgrade that you've neglected to mention.. 3) Create an issue on the repository in order to get the author's attention and advice, and potentially improve the library API or documentation as a result.

Comment: these are all good suggestions. I don't want to pin Fmt 0.8 as I think this crash is exposing a flaw in my code. I tried 1) and have added some info about that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue stems indeed from the fact that you are both emitting Fmt tags and installing a tag printer that rejects those tags.

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your tag handling, so let me present the generic way to extend a formatter with new tags.
The idea is basically to update the current tag-printing functions present in the formatter with a version that handles the new tags and delegate the handling of unknowns tags to the pre-existing functions.

```ml
(** normally, when defining new tags, it is better to extend the `Format.stag` type rather than relying on parsing tags *)
type Format.stag += My_tag of Lexer.t


let extend_tags_with_my_tag ppf =
  (* first, we get the existing tag-handling functions *)
  let parent = Format.pp_get_formatter_stag_functions ppf () in
  let print_open_stag stag = begin match stag with
    | Format.String_tag s ->
        (* backward-compatibility path *)
        begin match Lexer.tag_to_code @@ String.lowercase_ascii s with
        | Ok s -> Stack.push s stack
        | Error e ->
          (* we don't know this string tag,
             we delegate to the original function *)
          parent.print_open_stag stag
      end
    | My_tag lex -> 
      (* with a stag, there is no need for parsing *)
      Stack.push lex stack
    | stag -> 
      (* we let the parent handler takes care of the unknown tags *)
      parent.print_open_stag stag
  end;
    collapse stack
  in
  let print_close_stag stag = match stag with
    | My_tag lex -> ignore (Stack.pop stack)
    | Format.String_tag s as stag ->
      begin
        match Lexer.tag_to_code @@ String.lowercase_ascii s with
        | Ok s -> ignore (Stack.pop stack)
        | Error e -> parent.print_close_stag stag
      end
    | _ -> parent.print_close_stag stag
  in
  (* updating the original record is probably better
     for future-compatibility *)
  { parent with print_open_stag; print_close_stag }
```

Note that I am using `print_open_stag` and `print_close_stag` because there are generally more useful than the mark version.

EDIT: Concerning the mark functions, they mostly fit a debugging purpose. Typically,

```ml
Format.set_mark_tags true; Format.printf "@{<tag>content@}"
```

prints

```
<tag>contents</tag>
```

where both `<tag>` and `</tag>` are ignored in term of formatting.
However, more often than not, the elaboration of tags needs to print break hints, boxes, some formatted contents or even other tags. And that doesn't fit with the mark API. In this case, it is simply better to go for the `print` variants.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this approach this evening!  FWIW I read the docs for `mark_open_stag` vs `print_open_stag` a few times already and couldn't really understand what the distinction was supposed to be

Comment: I added some information about the distinction between the print and mark functions that hopefully may help.

Comment: just changing the case to `| _ -> ignore @@ parent.mark_open_stag stag` fixed the crash but I get the 'debug' output like `<tag>contents</tag>` rather than the transformed output from my stag code. So it seems like Alcotest+Fmt is clobbering my formatter somehow, yet at the same time my code runs too (else there'd be no crash). I can see that Fmt only sets the `mark_*` and not the `print_*` funcs so probably switching to print will "work" but would break again if my lib is ever combined with another that sets the print funcs

Comment: I think ultimately what I'm confused about is why the `Format.String_tag s` case does not get matched any more when running under Alcotest+Fmt... if I change that case to `| Format.String_tag s -> raise SomeError` nothing is raised.

Comment: Both the mark and pring tags branch need to be enable with `pp_set_print_tag` (resp. `pp_set_mark_tag`. It looks like `Fmt` is using the `mark` branch rather than the `print` one. Thus if you want to cooperate with `Fmt` coloring, you need to use the `mark`  version of the tag-handling functions contrarily to my initial advice.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sorry my question is bad, I can see I need to reduce it down to a minimal example. I am calling `Format.pp_set_mark_tags ppf true` and using only the mark funcs but for some reason the `Format.String_tag s` case doesn't match, only the fallthru case. Yet on the Fmt side it seems like my stag func is getting called by _their_ fallthru case. I don't really understand what is happening or how best to debug it